# How to shorten long underlines from query results in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

I am scheduling the a query to a table for each database in a particular instance. The query and table for each database are similar. I direct the query results to text file. Before the query results, I include the database where the particular query is being made. In my test in AdventureWorks, however, the result I got is a database name with very long underline.

Below is the output I got:

```
DatabaseName
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AdventureWorks                                                                                                                          

AttemptDate             
----------------------- 
2009-05-29 12:54:28.460
```

Below is the query I invoked:

```
set nocount on
use AdventureWorks
GO
select DB_NAME()as DatabaseName
select AttemptDate from dbo.ChangeAttempt
```

My question is: How do I shorten the lines below the database name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT LEFT(DB_NAME(), 20) AS DatabaseName
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I just increase the 20 to 40 to accomodate long database name which I notice in some of the databases.

Answer (score 2):

**use LEFT()**

try this:

```
declare @mytabel table (longvalue  varchar(1000))

select longvalue from @mytabel

select left(longvalue,50) as longvalue from @mytabel
```

output:

```
longvalue
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)

longvalue
--------------------------------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Huh.  I learned something new today.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: in text mode, sql server will put one "-" minus char for each possible character len of the column.  reduce the possible max length and you get fewer "-" minus characters...

Answer (score -1):

What output would you get from this query?

```
set nocount on
use AdventureWorks
GO
select DB_NAME() as DatabaseName, AttemptDate from dbo.ChangeAttempt
```